# how to generate row name for HBase insert data in java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Using java API I want to insert data in my HBase database. I need to create a put class before inserting ,like this :

```
Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
```

My program take data from user and put in database but the problem is row name (here row1) is needed for inserting but I don't know how to generate it uniquely and automatically, because for every row it should be different and if not it overwrite data.

Here is my code:

```
String fName, lName, number ;
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    System.out.println("Wainting for taking new phone number info ...\n");
    System.out.println("Please Enter first name : ");
    fName = in.nextLine() ;
    System.out.println("Please Enter last name : ");
    lName = in.nextLine() ;
    System.out.println("Please Enter number : ");
    number = in.nextLine() ;


    Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    HTable hTable = new HTable(config, "phoneList");
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("firstName")
            ,Bytes.toBytes(fName));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("personal"), Bytes.toBytes("lastName")
            ,Bytes.toBytes(lName));
    p.add(Bytes.toBytes("phone"), Bytes.toBytes("number")
            ,Bytes.toBytes(number));
    hTable.put(p);
    hTable.close();

    in.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want the rowkey to be. Within HBase, as row key is the only index and when you try to use the same rowkey and try to insert the data in the column which is already present, it will try to override the data. You can verify it with the timestamp associated with it. If you specify a new column, the data won't be overridden.

One way can be to fetch the last row of the table and increment the value and insert the row within the table:

```
Scan bigtableScan = new Scan();
List<Result> getResults = null;
try(ResultScanner bigTableResults = bigtableTable.getScanner(bigtableScan)){
    getResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Result bigTableResult = bigTableResults.next(); (bigTableResult != null); 
       bigTableResult = bigTableResults.next()) {
         getResults.add(bigTableResult);
    }
}
```

Navigate to the last row from the result list. To get the row from the result, all you can do:

```
for(Result hbaseResult : getResult){
     String rowKey = Bytes.toString(hbaseResult.getRow());
}
```

Once, you have the last row, you can apply your own logic to get a new row and insert the row within the table.

Answer (score 0):

`rowkey` is not a row name. Actually it is a row key for each column. It is required to provide a row key when you want to insert or alter a row in HBase.

Based on [HBase Documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#rowkey.design), increamenting/generating row keys are problematic in BigTable-like datastores and it is not recommended.

You can check if rowkey exists following below:

```
Get get = new Get(rowkey);
Result result = htable.get(get);
if (!result.isEmpty()) {
throw new Exception("Row with this key already exists.");
}
```